# add a class attribute to an actionlink that has a routevaluedictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im using an action link and passing in  tRVD where tRVD is the following:

```
<% RouteValueDictionary   tRVD = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values); %>
```

heres my link.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Index", tRVD)%>
```

how do i add a class attribute to this href?

i tried this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Index", tRVD, new { @class = "left" })%>
```

but it breaks the tRVD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´re using an incorrect overload of the ActionLink method.
Why don´t you try with

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Index", tRVD, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "left" } })%>
```

Regards.